# Error in the official examples of Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried downloading the example at this [link](https://developer.android.com/samples/RepeatingAlarm/index.html) and the following error is reported to me by Android Studio:

> Error:Failed to crunch file
>   C:\Users\Admin\Scuola\AndroidSample_httpsdeveloper.android.comsamplesCommitContentSampleAppindex.html\Download_Extract\RepeatingAlarm\Application\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.0.1\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png into
>   C:\Users\Admin\Scuola\AndroidSample_httpsdeveloper.android.comsamplesCommitContentSampleAppindex.html\Download_Extract\RepeatingAlarm\Application\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png

Does it happen to you too?
What is it?

Thanks for every help

Comment: you need to do this thing..On the main menu, choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart. The Invalidate Caches message appears informing you that the caches will be invalidated and rebuilt on the next start. Use buttons in the dialog to invalidate caches, restart IntelliJ IDEA or both.

Answer (score 0):

This directory is wrong, not Application\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\ is  app/src/main/res/drawable